# add_action outside a plugin

Tags: include

I'm trying to create my own class to make some of the most common changes I need in all my WP sites. Things like removing the canonical tag when not required or changing the meta description.

I'm not creating a plugin, as I'm not familiar with it.

I have written the following class, but I've been not able to get it fully working. As soon as _setup function has been called, anything else is outputted on the source code. Similarly all the add_action('wp_head') are ignored.

I suspect that this is because I am recalling the class too late, but I don't know whether this is the case and how I can test it.

```
    class Stuff_Frontend {
    private static $_instance = null;

    public static function init()
    {
        add_action( 'wp_head', array(self::instance(), '_setup'));
    }

    public static function instance()
    {
        // create a new object if it doesn't exist.
        is_null(self::$_instance) && self::$_instance = new self;
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Setup the class
     * Adds and removes a lot of filters.
     */
    function _setup() {
        echo "I'm here;";
        add_action( 'wp_head', array(self::instance(), 'head' ), 1 );

        // Remove actions that we will handle through our wpseo_head call, and probably change the output of
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_canonical' );
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'index_rel_link' );
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link' );
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head' );
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rsd_link' );
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link' );

        add_action( 'mystuff', array(self::instance(), 'change_metadesc' ), 10 );
    }

    /**
     * Main wrapper function attached to wp_head. This combines all the output on the frontend.
     */
    public function head() {
        echo "this is a test for my class head";

        /**
         * Action: 'mystuff'
         */
        do_action( 'mystuff' );

        return;
    }   

    /**
     * Change the meta description element.
     *
     * @param bool $echo Whether or not to echo the description.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function change_metadesc() {

        echo "this is an attempt to change the description";
    }
    }
```

The class above is recalled in the function.php ini using the following statements:

```
include( locate_template( 'MyStuff.php' ) );
Stuff_Frontend::init();
```

Any hint is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You add your `_setup` function to `wp_head` without priority, so it's given priority of 20. All of the actions you are trying to remove within that function either have a higher priority (lower number), or same priority but are already in the queue ahead of yours, so when your `_setup` function runs, they've already sent their output. There's no reason to wait until `wp_head` to remove those actions, you can do it on the `init` action.

Also FYI, all your file needs is a [plugin header](http://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header) and it'll be a stand-alone plugin.

Comment: But I have the priority set in the _setup function for the wp_head call in the _setup funciont. Adding a priority for the _setup call in the init resulted only in my "I'm here" echo message appear just a little above, but all the other echo messages are still not on the screen.

Comment: BTW by moving the remove_actions in the init does work, but I don't need to set a priority. If I do set it to 1, they don't work. I suspect that also removing bit in WP requires a knowledge of when something is executed?

Comment: inside `init()` function you add your setup function with no priority, so it runs on priority 20. in `_setup()`, you add something to `wp_head` with priority 1, but that already happened before your function executed, because you're now at priority 20. I wasn't suggesting you add a priority to the remove actions, all that matters is when your code that calls those remove actions executes, you're trying to remove things after they've already happened.

Comment: I see .. thanks for pointing me out on the mistake.